# Google Maps Markers setPosition leaves old marker on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, angularjs

Pretty simple implementation of Google Maps on AngularJS.  The following code works perfect on my desktop using FireFox.  However, on my android this code leaves the old marker after I click to change positions.  I can drag around the map and "wake" it up.  The data behind the map is correct but it just won't refresh the marker overlay.  Can I force it to refresh?  Am I doing something wrong?

```
$scope.mapOptions = {
    center: myLatlng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

$scope.setMarkerPosition = function($event) {
    $scope.marker.setPosition($event.latLng);
}

$scope.$watch('myMap', function(map) {
    if (map) {
        $scope.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.myMap,
            position: myLatlng
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The built-in Android browser comes with quite a lot of bugs, unfortunately. Is it the same if you try Chrome/Firefox on your phone?

Comment: Unfortunately it is running on PhoneGap so I don't have a choice.

Comment: how about chrome on your desktop?

Comment: Experiencing the same problem on chrome on android